# Htaccess Rerwite Urls

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^hash/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) hash.php?key=$1 [QSA,L]
```

so that transforming url from

```
hash.php?key=anything
```

To

```
 hash/anything
```

Works fine

But when i goes to hash/anything all urls in page have this schema

hash/anything/some_image.jpg

but i want to refer all links to root because that is meanningless

hash/some_image.jpg

so how can i refer all links to root when iam navigating to diffrent hashes !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this in your html page header:

```
<base href="/">
```